# Методы уже определены в *.obj + интерфейс

Tags: c++, объекты, интерфейс

Нужно было реализовать интерфейс используя только элементы модульного программирования
Ошибка что метод уже определен в другом объекте

```
//main cpp
#include "Container.h" 
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    typedef void* Cont;
    Cont l = cont_allocate();
    Cont A = cont_allocate();
    //cont_add(l, (void*)1);

    system("pause");
}

//container.h
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef void(*cont_handle)(void* data);
void* cont_allocate();          // Создает пустой контейнер
void  cont_release(void* cont); // Удаляет контейнер
void  cont_add(void* cont, void* data); // Добавляет элемент в  конец контейнера
void  cont_insert(void* cont, int pos, void* data); // Вставляет элемент в позицию pos
int   cont_size(void* cont);    // Возвращает размер контейнера
void* cont_get(void* cont, int pos);    // Возвращает данные в позиции pos
void* cont_replace(void* cont, int pos, void* data);    // Заменяет данные в    позиции pos.  Возвращает старые данные.
void* cont_remove(void* cont, int pos); // Удаляет данные из позиции pos. Возвращает удаленные данные.
void  cont_foreach(void* cont, cont_handle proc);   // Перебирает все элементы контейнера по порядку.
void  cont_foreach_reverse(void* cont, cont_handle proc);   //Перебирает все элементы контейнера в обратном порядке.

//ListArray.cpp
struct list
{
    int field; // поле данных
    list *next; // указатель на следующий элемент
    list *prev; // указатель на предыдущий элемент

    
};
    

void* cont_allocate()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    list *lst;
    // выделение памяти под корень списка
    lst = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    lst->next = NULL; // указатель на следующий узел
    lst->prev = NULL;
    std::cout << "dq";
    return lst;
}

//DinamicArray.cpp
#include "Container.h"

struct Darray
{
public:
    int size; // поле данных
    void* arr;
};


void* cont_allocate()
{
    Darray *drr;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    drr = (Darray*)malloc(sizeof(Darray*));
    cout << "da";
    return drr;
}
```

Comment: void* cont_allocate() и void* cont_allocate() это 2 разных определения одной и тойже функции. В C++ так нельзя.

Answer (score 2):

У вас нарушено ODR (правило одного определения), присутствуют две реализации функции со следующей сигнатурой `void* cont_allocate();` у которой внешнее связывание, чтобы сделать связывание для функции внутренним (то есть чтобы видимость была в пределе одной единицы трансляции) можно поместить функцию в анонимный `namespace` или сделать её `static`.

для определения в пределах одной единицы трансляции:

1. с анонимным `namespace`:

   ```
   namespace 
   {
     void* cont_allocate()
     {
     }
   }
   ```
2. `static`

   ```
   static void* cont_allocate()
   {
   }
   ```

если хотите функции с одинаковыми сигнатурами, но чтобы было внешнее связывание можно поместить их в разные неанонимные пространства имён

Comment: А как тогда сделать, чтобы вызывалась нужная функция.

Comment: @HackedCup186 если ваша функция в пределах одного модуля, то если она `static` то вызывается как обычно если в анонимном `namespace` то следующим образом: `::имя_функции(параметры)`

Comment: не в пределах одного модуля вызывается(должна в мейне)

Comment: @HackedCup186 сделайте их тогда в разных `namespace` не анонимных